# When do i need to install Sql server 2012 or others

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm planing on learning web programming. Wanted to start from databases and servers.
And was wondering when do i need to install sql server 20xx or others?
As i understand in windows 7 there is already somekind sql server?
What kind of server would you advice to install if needed?
More advance explanations are welcome, also tips on from were to start.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: hmm, well.. many options exist. SQL server though? for beginn. web programming? I might advise MySQL. LAMP stack etc

Comment: I can't make a suggestion on *which* SQL server to learn, but if you're using Visual Studio for anything, odds are you already have SQL Server 2012 installed. VS installs it and seems to rely on it, since I once tried uninstalling SQL Server and my VS started complaining.

Comment: There are some decent free projects out there, code to play with.

Comment: Yes indeed i'm using visual studio 2012. Then i see no point atleast for now to install anything else. :) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As i understand in windows 7 there is already some kind sql server?

No.  Visual Studio 2012 does, but not Windows 7.

> when do i need to install sql server 20xx or others?

You'll probably want *some* edition of SQL server as soon as you want to persist data.

> What kind of server would you advice to install if needed?

Since you mentioned SQL Server (assuming MS SQL Server), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) for the differences between different editions of Microsoft SQL Server.  SQL Express is a good starting spot to develop locally, but you'll want a full-featured edition (Web at the minimum) when you actually publish the site.

Note that many hosts include some SQL capabilities in their pricing.

Of course, there are other options as well if you're not settled on MS.

Comment: Thank you. That mostly explains alot, also will try to explore the topic.